# Laravel update database error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update a table. and I receive this error

```
Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'B2AFE7CB-3451-4C73-9948-C3DD2B21F949' (SQL: update `match_histories` set `format_type` = 0, `user_score` = 2, `opponent_score` = 0, `ended_at` = 2017-05-08 02:07:39, `opponent_ign` = poudigne, `user_champion` = Kagulichu, `opponent_champion` = Uzzu the Bonewalker where `match_id` = 35339) in /home/vagrant/hexstatstracker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
```

My code to update :

```
$udt_arr = array(
   'format_type' => $tour_data['Format'],
   'user_score'=> $myScore,
   'opponent_score'=> $oppScore,
   'ended_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'opponent_ign' => $oppName,
   'user_champion' => $ongoing_match->user_champion,
   'opponent_champion' => $ongoing_match->opponent_champion,
);

DB::table('match_histories')
    ->where('match_id', $match_id)
    ->update($udt_arr);
```

Comment: You may already have invalid data in the column, which would stop the query from executing correctly.

Comment: Your `ended_at` column must have data type `timestamp` . have you checked that?

Comment: Please print your `$udt_arr` array here as need to check the all values for same

Comment: Fixed by switching my ID to autoincrements instead of GUID. For an unknow reason PHP seems to transform the GUID into a double